# DjangoREST using DELETE and UPDATE with serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I followed the [Quickstart Guide](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) on the DjangoREST framewok site and ended up with the following code:

**serializers.py:**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Group
    fields = ('url', 'name')
```

**views.py:**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
"""
queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
serializer_class = UserSerializer

class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
"""
queryset = Group.objects.all()
serializer_class = GroupSerializer
```

**urls.py:**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)
router.register(r'rooms', views.RoomViewSet)
router.register(r'devices', views.DeviceViewSet)
router.register(r'deviceTypes', views.DeviceTypeViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',  namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Now this all works fine, but I cant find out how to DELETE or UPDATE a user or a group, seems I can only add users and groups and view them.
So my question is:
How can I modify this code to make it possible to delete/update users and groups?

Comment: please indent your code correctly

Answer (score 5):

The code is fine, you just need to use `PUT` and `DELETE` data methods for update and delete respectively (instead of `GET/POST`)

You can see from the code example for a `ModelViewSet` in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#refactoring-to-use-viewsets)

```
class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
```

and the docs for [`ModelViewSet`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)

> The actions provided by the ModelViewSet class are `.list()`, `.retrieve()`, `.create()`, `.update()`, `.partial_update()`, and `.destroy()`.

Comment: @Robert - No worries, enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You must perform a HTTP request with method DELETE without any header and body.
example

```
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/persona/4/
```

only for contrast, the create will be perform the next CURL (note the header "Content-Type"):

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/persona/ -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
"nombre": "Rick",
"apellidos": "Isenhower",
"edad": "38",
telefono": "8547458858", 
"domicilio": "St Utha, Colorado"}'
```

Cheers C:

Answer (score 0):

Use 'curl' or 'httpie' to perform **DELETE** or **UPDATE** or any other request.

Example:

```
http DELETE example.org/todos/7

or

curl -X "DELETE" http://www.url.com/page
```

See details here:

1. https://httpie.org/doc
2. https://www.garron.me/en/bits/curl-delete-request.html